# SQL Server Connection String: Web Hosting Service providing connection string that doesn't seem right

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, connection-string, membership-provider

I have an ASP.NET C# application with a SQL server 2008 R2 database that has consolidated membership provider and application database.  I am trying to modify my web config according to the instructions provided by the web hosting service provider but I think I'm missing something.

Here is my current web.config connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="RestaurantDB" connectionString="data source=SFP\SFP_SQL_SVR;attachdbfilename=C:\Users\Susan\Documents\Databases\Restaurants.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>

<add name="RestaurantsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Restaurant.csdl|res://*/Restaurant.ssdl|res://*/Restaurant.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SFP\SFP_SQL_SVR;attachdbfilename=C:\Users\Susan\Documents\Databases\Restaurants.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

Here is the connection string that the web hosting service has given me:

```
Data Source=RESTAURANT.db.9319451.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=RESTAURANT; User ID=your username; Password='your password';
```

How do I modify my current connection strings in light of the above?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `data source=SFP\SFP_SQL_SVR;attachdbfilename=C:\Users\Susan\Documents\Databases\Restaurants.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;`

to

`Data Source=RESTAURANT.db.9319451.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=RESTAURANT; User ID=your username; Password='your password';`

Like :

```
<add name="RestaurantDB" connectionString="data source=RESTAURANT.db.9319451.hostedresource.com; 
Initial Catalog=RESTAURANT; User ID=your username; Password='your password'> 

<add name="RestaurantsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Restaurant.csdl|res://*/Restaurant.ssdl|res://*/Restaurant.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=RESTAURANT.db.9319451.hostedresource.com; 
Initial Catalog=RESTAURANT; User ID=your username; Password='your password;
multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to deal with this but I'm just giving you an idea. Try it may be it works
First modify your **RestaurantDB** connection string like this

```
<add name="RestaurantDB" connectionString="RESTAURANT.db.9319451.hostedresource.com;Initial Catalog=RESTAURANT; User ID=your username; Password='your password';"/>
```

and **RestaurantsEntities** like this

```
<add name="RestaurantsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Restaurant.csdl|res://*/Restaurant.ssdl|res://*/Restaurant.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=RESTAURANT.db.9319451.hostedresource.com;Initial Catalog=RESTAURANT;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

If the above does not work then also add UserID and Password in the RestaurantsEntities connection string